# Default analyzers in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, elastic-stack

I have added the following in my yml file.
index :
analysis :
analyzer :
default :
tokenizer : keyword

But when I am seeing my index metadata at head plugin I am not able to find these index_analyzer and search_analyzer in 2.1.1. I was able to see these two fileds in metadata in the previous version of ES 1.1.1 index.

I am not sure if these analyzers are getting applied on the index while indexing and searching? Is there anyway we can test the custom analyzers created on index??

```
{
  "state": "open",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "creation_date": "1453297871538",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "autocomplete_filter": {
            "type": "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram": "1",
            "max_gram": "20"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "autocomplete_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_shards": "4",
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "uuid": "L35y69StSXClxT5yvj95Uw",
      "version": {
        "created": "2010199"
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "itemsnew": {
      "properties": {
        "ERP_PRICE_LIST_ID": {
          "include_in_all": false,
          "type": "long"
        },
        "ITEM_NUMBER_AUTO": {
          "search_analyzer": "standard",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "SERVICE_FLAG": {
          "include_in_all": false,
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "PROGRAM_ID_RAW": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "IS_ACTIVE": {
          "include_in_all": false,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "PROGRAM_ID": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": [
    "sample"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the result of `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`? Make sure to replace `your_index` by your actual index name.

Comment: I am not able to find the below in this newly created index:            
                             
       itemsnew: {
           index_analyzer: default_index
           search_analyzer: default_search
      }

I have added the entry  index.analysis.analyzer.default.type: keyword in yml file    @Val